# Invalid Code Signing Identity because of an expired certificate that doesn't exist

Tags: certificate, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I'm stuck with my app. I can't upload it to iTunes because, after the "Archive" step when I have to choose an application record and a Code Signing Identity it says:

> "My Name" is a valid identity. However, the associated package identity "My Name" has expired.

Looking in the popup menu of Code Sign Identity I notice that the problem comes from the "MyProgram_production" certificate, and in fact in the provisioning portal, when I go to create the developer certificate profile for Production I get this error:

> You must have a valid Mac Application Certificate to create a Provisioning Profile.

[image: You must have a valid Mac Application Certificate to create a Provisioning Profile]

But I already created a valid provisioning profile, as you can see in the image it is there, but the expired one is also there.
My problem is that in the certificates page of the Apple site, the old expired one is not there. There are some old certificates but I have no chance to delete them:

[image: the certficates page]

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 2 days of total desperation... (I should be used being an Apple Dev for some years now...) I finally resolved my problem...
For who is having the same difficulty the problem was I could not see the expired certificates in my Keychain Access and that is because there was the (strange) option "Hide Expired Certificates" in my comp... I changed Mac and had no idea there was this option...
Why someone should want to hide an expired certificate and not just delete it???
Anyway deleting the expired certs and doing all the certificates again on Apple site did the trick!

Comment: Thank you so much for updating your question, we had the exact same issue and had been searching for days.  Even spent 3 hours with Apple tech support without finding this solution.

Comment: You're welcome... You should report this as a bug... I already did it... if more developers will do this it will be changed by Apple.. so no one in the future will have to lose hours of their lives for something so stupid... ;) 
Here's the link for bug reporting: https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ Peace... Massy

Comment: Thank you!! If it helps anyone the option is under `View` in the menu bar.

Comment: Damn! 10 hours digging around for that stupid stupid settings. Go to Keychain > View > Hide Expired Certificats and toggle it off! Merde!

Answer (score 0):

You have to revoke and have to create new certificate. It clearly says "You must have a valid Mac Application Certificate to create a Provisioning Profile. So you have to generate valid certificate starting from keychain.

Comment: As you can see in the image I uploaded I already created a new valid Mac Application Certificate... (the one that Expires on 17 feb 2014)... but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you created certificate or provision?

Comment: Both, I created in Certificate: Mac Installer, Mac App, Mac Development and in Provisioning: myapp_development and myapp_production... but when I go to do the production I always get that error signed in red, and there is that Mac App Certificate expired on 5 feb 2013 that is not in the certificate page... so I have no chance to revoke it